# JSDoc "Requires" appears twice?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Is it normal for "Requires" to appears twice in the output documentation?  If not, what is the correct way to document required modules so they appear only once?

```
//Imports
import * as C from "../support/constants.js";
import Dispatcher from "../support/Dispatcher.js";

/**
 * @description The <strong>TextField</strong> class creates instances of either clickable and animatable text or static text accessible via the <strong>"element"</strong> property.
 * @class
 * @requires constants
 * @requires Dispatcher
 * 
 */
class TextField extends Dispatcher {

    /**
     * @param {string} label - Textual content set as the <strong>"textContent"</strong> property of the TextField's HTMLElement.
     * @param {string} id - DOMString representing the <strong>"id"</strong> property of the TextField's HTMLElement.
     * @param {string} href - The URL assigned to the <strong>"href"</strong> property of the TextField's HTMLElement.
     * 
     */
    constructor(label, id, href) {

        super();

        this._label = label;
        this._id = id;
        this._href = href;

        this._init();
    }

    ...
```

[image]

Comment: Is it grabbing them from the import declaration AND adding them from your comments? What happens if you remove `* @requires constants`?

Comment: I thought that was the problem, too, but If I remove `@requires constants` and `@requires Dispatcher` then "Requires" doesn't appear in the output docs at all.